# Adding CSS content property after '<div id="name">' simultaneously on a rectangle

Tags: html, css

I am creating a picture framing calculator.  When the calculator solves the user input - it displays the answer on a rectangle.  The problem I'm running into is that the unit of measurement, `"`, is displaying on the rectangle before the answer is calculated.  The answer **and** inches symbol should display simultaneously.  Here's my code:

```css
#height {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 250px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#height::after {
  content: "\0022";
}

#width::after {
  content: "\0022";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>I Was Framed - Calculator</title>



        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

    </head>

<body>
 
        
<section>
    
    <form id="frm1" action="/index.html" method="post">

<fieldset>

<legend>

I Was Framed Calculator

</legend>



<label for="frameWidth">Frame Width:</label><input type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="frameWidth" id="frameWidth"><select name="frameWidthFraction" id="frameWidthFraction">
    <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.875">7/8</option> 
                <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
</select>

<label for="frameHeight">Frame Height:</label><input type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="frameHeight" id="frameHeight"><select name="frameHeightFraction" id="frameHeightFraction">
    
    <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
                <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
</select>



<label for="pictureWidth">Picture Width:</label><input type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="pictureWidth" id="pictureWidth"><select name="pictureWidthFraction" id="pictureWidthFraction">
    
    <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
                <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
</select>

<label for="pictureHeight">Picture Height:</label><input type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="pictureHeight" id="pictureHeight">


<select name="pictureHeightFraction" id="pictureHeightFraction">
   
    <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
                <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
</select><br>

<label for="matOverlap">Mat Overlap:</label><input type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0" name="matOverlap" id="matOverlap"><select name="matOverlapFraction" id="matOverlapFraction">
    
    <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
            <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                <option value="0.875">7/8</option>
                <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
</select>

    <br>


<br>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc"/>

</fieldset>

</form>

</section>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fractional@1.0.0/index.js"></script>

<script>

function calc()

{

    var frameWidth = document.getElementById('frameWidth').value
    frameWidth = parseInt(frameWidth)
    
    var frameWidthFraction = document.getElementById('frameWidthFraction').value
    frameWidthFraction = parseFloat(frameWidthFraction)
        
    var frameHeight = document.getElementById('frameHeight').value
    frameHeight = parseInt(frameHeight)

    var frameHeightFraction = document.getElementById('frameHeightFraction').value
    frameHeightFraction = parseFloat(frameHeightFraction)
    
    var pictureWidth = document.getElementById('pictureWidth').value
    pictureWidth = parseInt(pictureWidth)

    var pictureWidthFraction = document.getElementById('pictureWidthFraction').value
    pictureWidthFraction = parseFloat(pictureWidthFraction)

    var pictureHeight = document.getElementById('pictureHeight').value
    pictureHeight = parseInt(pictureHeight)

    var pictureHeightFraction = document.getElementById('pictureHeightFraction').value
    pictureHeightFraction = parseFloat(pictureHeightFraction)

    var matOverlap = document.getElementById('matOverlap').value
    matOverlap = parseInt(matOverlap)

    var matOverlapFraction = document.getElementById('matOverlapFraction').value
    matOverlapFraction = parseFloat(matOverlapFraction)

    if (isNaN(frameWidth) || isNaN(frameHeight) || isNaN(pictureWidth) || isNaN(pictureHeight) || isNaN(matOverlap)) {
    alert('All fields are required!')
    return
}

   var width = (1/2)*((frameHeight+frameHeightFraction)-(pictureHeight+pictureHeightFraction)+(matOverlap+matOverlapFraction));
   var height = (1/2)*((frameWidth+frameWidthFraction)-(pictureWidth+pictureWidthFraction)+(matOverlap+matOverlapFraction));

   document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = new Fraction(width).toString();
   document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = new Fraction(height).toString();

   document.getElementById('rectangle').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'})

}

</script>
        

    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;width:400px;height:50px;border:5px solid #000; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 50px;padding-bottom:75%;background-color:gray" id="rectangle">
        <center>
            <div id="width"></div>
        </center>
    
        <div id="height"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see on the rectangle - the `"` at the `width` and `height` locations are already present **before** the calculation is done.

This is the CSS code I've tried:

```
#height::after {
  content: "\0022";
}

#width::after {
  content: "\0022";
}
```

Can I get some guidance on how to make the calculator output and the `"` symbol appear simultaneously?

Comment: `"message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "https://unpkg.com/fractional@1.0.0/index.js",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what you've tried with the pseudo elements that is causing problems.  That psuedo element will be there as long as `#height` and `#width` are on the DOM.

Two solutions:

1. Create a special style rule like `.ticks` or something.  Add that class to width and height after calculating the value.

```
.ticks::after {
  content: "\0022";
}

document.getElementById('width').classList.add("ticks");
document.getElementById('height').classList.add("ticks");
```

2. Simply add the `"` symbol to the end of the string being shown in the frame after calculating.

```
document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = new Fraction(width).toString() + '"';
document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = new Fraction(height).toString() + '"';
```